# Motion Problem with Two Objects Moving

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cyclist departs from a place. 12 minutes later, a message-carrying motorcyclist departs from the same place. The motor cyclist and the cyclist meet at a place 9 miles away from their departing place. The motorcyclist immediately goes back to their departing place. Upon arrival, the motorcyclist goes after the cyclist again. They meet again 18 miles away from their departing place. How fast does the cyclist ride? How fast does the motorist ride?

I almost have it, but not quite. I know that the speed of the motorist is 3 times the speed of the cyclist.

Comment: If the motorist is traveling at 3 times the speed of the cyclist, then the motorist takes $1/3$ the time to travel the first 9 mile stretch that the bike takes. So from the information that the bicycle had a 12 minute head start, you can work out how long the motorist took to travel 9 miles.

Comment: That is what I have a problem with.

Comment: The numbers aren't very realistic, btw.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: The bike had a 12 minute head start, and takes a total of three times the amount of time to travel 9 miles that the motorcyclist takes. You can't work out how long the motorcyclist takes from that information?

Comment: An equation isn't really necessary here, but try $t_b = 12 + t_m$, where $t_b$ is the time the bicyclist takes to travel $9$ miles and $t_m$ is the time the motorist takes to travel $9$ miles. You've already worked out that $t_b = 3 t_m$.

Comment: It takes 6 minuutes for motorist to travel 9 miles so motorist is 90mph (wow) and the cyclist  is 30 mph.

Comment: yes! That's perfect. The bicyclist, of course, does not deserve a wow for traveling 30 mph. :-)

Comment: Who. Voted. Down. My. Question. For. No. Reason!!

Comment: Hit and run downvotes are not cool.

Comment: It was removed, thankfully

Comment: Why is this on hold?

Comment: I think it's on hold because mathematicians prefer to communicate their complaints through a cold heartless interface, rather than through proper conversation to explain the exact issues. As far as I can tell, you did a pretty decent job of explaining your work. The only honest reason I can see for closing down this question is that it's too basic (i.e. high school level instead of university level).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:

"This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." This is what they said...

Comment: I know, I can see that. And as I said, your question doesn't appear to fail to meet that need...

Comment: I reported this to the mods to ask them to remove, but I received no reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correct Answer:

As many of you have pointed out, and as I have soon come to realize, the motorcyclist travels 3 times the distance that the cyclist travels in the same amount of time: the motorcyclist travels 9 miles back to the starting point and then 18 miles to meet the cyclist, a total of 27 miles, while the cyclist travels 9 miles from the first meeting point to the second.

Since the motorcyclist travels 3 times as fast as the cyclist, the motorcyclist would have gone 27 miles in the time it took the cyclist to go  9. The motorcyclist waited 12 minutes and then traveled 9 miles, or 1/3rd of 27 miles. This means 12 minutes is 2/3rds of the time it takes the motorcyclist to go 27 miles.

27 miles / 18 minutes = **90 miles per hour.**

The cyclist travels at 1/3rd that speed, or **30 miles per hour.**

@DustanLevenstein, I'm very sorry about my mistake.

### Incorrect Answer:

- It takes `x - 12` minutes for the motorcyclist to go `9` miles.
- Therefore, if the motorcyclist is moving at a constant speed, it takes `3(x - 12)` minutes for the motorcyclist to go `9 + 18 = 27` miles.
- So, in total, it has taken the cyclist `4(x - 12)` minutes to go `18` miles, and it has taken the motorcyclist `4(x - 12)` minutes to go `36` miles.
- The motorcyclist is moving twice as fast as the cyclist.
- Because the motorcyclist is going twice as fast as the cyclist, and they both met at `9` miles, with the motorcyclist waiting `12` minutes, we know that the motorcyclist went `9` miles in `12` minutes.
- So the motorcyclist's speed is `9` miles per `12` minutes, or `45` miles per hour.
- The cyclist's speed is half of that of the motorcyclist, so the cyclist's speed is `22.5` miles per hour.

@DustanLevenstein, I'm fairly certain that the motorcyclist is actually traveling *four* times as fast as the cyclist, not three.

Comment: @Anonymous what don't you know? Please tell me where the mistake is so I can remove my answer if necessary.

Comment: I don't know if it is your answer or DustinLevenstein's answer that is correct.

Comment: @Anonymous, Dustin was almost correct. I think he missed the part where the motorcyclist travels back to the starting place, a total of additional 9 miles. This makes the total distance traveled by the motorcyclist 36 miles, twice that of the cyclist.

Comment: no, it's three times. In the time that the bicyclist travels $9$ miles, the motorcyclist travels $2\cdot 9+9=27$ miles.